# How to save entries into db on submit button click only

Tags: php, mysql, http-post

I have a code like this

```
<?php
if ( $thismemberinfo[msurf] >= $msurfclicks ) {
    $sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO d_bonus VALUES('$userid','0.02',NOW())"); 
    echo "success";
} else {
    echo "wrong";
}
?>
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
  <input type="hidden" value="123" name="match">
  <input type="submit" value="Claim your daily bonus $o.o2" name="submit1">
</form>
```

I want to save values into db after user clicks the submit button. I have been trying different approaches, but still could not get near to it.

Any ideas/hints what I should do next or doing wrong?

After the given suggesstion below is my code :

```
<form action="" method="post" name="myform">
<input type="hidden" value="123" name="match">
<input type="submit" value="Claim your daily bonus $o.o2" name="submit1">
</form>
<?php
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit1']))
{
echo "$thismemberinfo[msurf]";
echo " $msurfclicks";
if ( $thismemberinfo[msurf] >= $msurfclicks ) {
      //$sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO d_bonus VALUES('$userid','0.02',NOW())"); 
          echo "success";

}
else
{
echo " not set " ;
}

}

?>
```

Comment: check for $_POST['submit']

Comment: It works like this: PHP builds the page, and sends the page to the client. Afterwards, if the client so chooses, the client submits the form. The form POST's data (accessible via `$_POST`) to the server, which generates another PHP request. In that request you need to check for `$_POST` values then do whatever you want on the server side. Note, after the `$_POST` the server should send another response back to the client.

Comment: You should update your action on your form, action="YourPage.php", Although it may work well, it's recommended and better practise to fill it in.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you can use `isset` for checking if button is clicked or not

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['submit1']))
{

     if ( $thismemberinfo[msurf] >= $msurfclicks ) {
     $sql=$Db1->query("INSERT INTO d_bonus VALUES('$userid','0.02',NOW())"); 
     echo "success";
     }
     else
     {
        echo "wrong";
     }
 header("location:".$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
}
```

Comment: it works but partially . one the page refresh , it also runs the php code . thats whats is the problem for me .. I want to code only to run on button click. thanks for further suggesstions

Comment: i have edited the code u can check with this code if it works properly or not

Comment: @pateik .. it works partially .. it runs the query after the button click. now when i refresh the page , it again run the query. i.e. after one click if someone refershes the page it will keep on running the query. This is the problem i am not able to handle well ..

Comment: this code has worked partially for me ,, i have applied some extra checks to keep it working .

Comment: try to redirect the page as i have done in above code

Comment: header("location:"$_REQUEST['PHP_SELF']);  ,, syntax error : I will check the the proper syntax and will try to implement it

Comment: header('Location: '.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);  ,  this is the proper syntax , but redirects to the main page .. not to the same page .. it opens the home page of the site . not the current page

Answer (score 1):

Your code is missing a few things..

To insert entries into the database, you should think more about what tasks need to be carried out, I'll give you a list of them, you have probably done some of these.

1) Connect to the database.
2) Obtain the values entered into the form, and store them in local variables, in your case you have used POST on your form and therefore.. here's an example:

```
$Field1 = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['match']); // match?? This post data comes from the name field of your form.
```

3) Create your query... e.g..

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO table_name (table_heading) VALUES ('$Field1')";
```

4) Run the query

Comment: bro , i guess u did not get my question. nothing is coming from the form, every thing outside the form.. and set .. i just want query to run on submit button click..

Comment: Nah I got it, your problem is your not obtaining the data your form is submitting, it is being sent out their, just your not doing anything with it, if you see part 2 of my answer, a good easy way of doing this is by obtaining the data in a variable, I'll update my part 2 for your fields you need obtaining, 2 secs.

Answer (score 1):

You need to check if the request has come from the post submit i.e. as others pointed check `$_POST['submit']`

```
if(isset( $_POST['submit'] ) {
    // your complete rest php code goes here to insert the record
}
```

On page refresh, it'll see the request is not a post request submitted hence won't execute the php code in the if and will just display the page.

Comment: i have updated the code ,, pls check and guide me whats wrong in the code . what's missing  ??